# Combine two tables in one table with SQL

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two simple SQL tables and I would to combine them into one table.
I would like to combine Table A (actually called view_gradedchallenges) and Table B (actually called view_totalpartpoints) into Table AB.

[image: Click here for an image that makes it clearer]

I read that a FULL OUTER JOIN might do the job, but that is not supported in MySQL for some reason. An alternative is a LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and then combine the two queries using UNION or UNION ALL. 
But that gives me the following result:

[image: Click here for an image that makes it clearer]

Can anybody help me to find the query that will generate Table AB?

This is the query I am currently using:

```
SELECT * from view_gradedchallenges LEFT OUTER JOIN view_totalpartpoints ON view_gradedchallenges.author = view_totalpartpoints.uid
UNION
SELECT * from view_gradedchallenges RIGHT OUTER JOIN view_totalpartpoints ON view_gradedchallenges.author = view_totalpartpoints.uid
```

If you would use the names TableA and TableB instead of their original names, this would be the query:

```
SELECT * from TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid
UNION
SELECT * from TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid
```

But unfortunately, this leads to the wrong result (see the left part of the second image).
I want to know how to solve this. Please help me (instead of showing a similar thread that doesn't answer this particular question)

Comment: And if that duplicate does not work for you then you should at least share your current query

Comment: This is my query:

SELECT * from view_gradedchallenges LEFT OUTER JOIN view_totalpartpoints ON view_gradedchallenges.author = view_totalpartpoints.uid
UNION
SELECT * from view_gradedchallenges RIGHT OUTER JOIN view_totalpartpoints ON view_gradedchallenges.author = view_totalpartpoints.uid
------
(If you would use 'TableA' and 'TableB' instead of their real names, this would be the query:

SELECT * from TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid
UNION
SELECT * from TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid)

But this gives the wrong result

Comment: Add it in a readable form into your question.

Comment: Sorry, added it

Comment: try this, I just renamed the author's column
SELECT author as uid, total_points, times_graded 
from TableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid

UNION 
SELECT uid, total_points, times_graded 
from TableA 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.author = TableB.uid

Comment: That's it, thank your very much!! I already tried "author as uid" after the first SELECT, but it didn't work since I also put it behind the second SELECT. Now that I just use "uid" after the second SELECT (as you suggest), it works great! Thank you so much!